# Komodo IDE 7 running code line by line

Tags: python, komodo

Is it possible to run a part of code in Komodo IDE 7 line by line?
For example my code using python:

```
lets = (1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7)
jets = list(lets)
count = 0
for i in range(len(lets)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(lets)):
        if lets[i] > lets[j]:
            count += 1
            print(count)
```

if i want to run only loop line by line to look step by step looping

Comment: The word you are looking for is "debug". [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pdb.html)

Comment: Have you used Komodo? Can't set debugging options.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about the Komodo IDE, but you can try out pdb (python debugger) or pylint for debugging python files.
eg.

```
pdb FileName.py
```

Pylint helps to check the source code bug and quality of the code.

Comment: pylint has nothing at all to do with debugging.

Comment: Tnx for advising Pylint

Answer (score 0):

you can use `yield` function for that. Like..

```
def GEN():
    lets = (4,5,9,4,3)
    jets = list(lets)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(lets)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lets)):
            if lets[i] > lets[j]:
                count += 1
                yield(count)
```

and take `LL = GEN()` & call by `LL.next()` sequentially . you can see `count` value step by step

```
>>> LL = GEN()
>>> LL.next()
1
>>> LL.next()
2
>>> LL.next()
3
.......
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Komodo for years, but it does have a built-in debugger. You can highlight a line, and click "set breakpoint", then when you run the file execution will stop at that point; you can then click the 'next' and 'step' buttons.